# Writing n number of lines above and below the line being appended to a text file in C#

Tags: c#

In the application I am working on, I created keyword searcher. The user uploads a textfile (since this is for work, it will be a txt file that has thousands of lines of messages) and can input multiple words to search for and the application pulls out any line with the corresponding input. The only problem is, they want to be able to also pull out n number of lines above and below the line that is being copied so they can see the context of the messages being pulled. Is there a way to say copy this line and n number of lines above and below this one? Below is my code for searching for the word and writing it.

```
 private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string[] sArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox7.Text);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     foreach (string line in sArray)
     {
          if (Regex.IsMatch(line, (textBox9.Text), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox9.Text))
          {
              sb.AppendLine(line);
          }

          if (Regex.IsMatch(line, (textBox10.Text), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox10.Text))
          {
              sb.AppendLine(line);
          }
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textBox8.Text))
        {
            sw.Write(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to build grep, right? I would use a `for` instead of `foreach`. In this way you have the possibility to "know" the line number of a match and do whatever you want ;-)

Comment: hmm don't know what a grep is, care to explain?

Comment: I've posted a little example how you could achieve it. You will have to call the method once per word.

Comment: Awesome! I'll take a look and let you know how it goes, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've provided a little example. You can use it like this:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>() {"This", "is", "some", "test", "data"};
List<string> result = GetMatchingLines(lines, "test", 2, 2);
```

The method looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all lines containing the "match" including "before" lines before and "after" lines after.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lines">The original lines.</param>
/// <param name="match">The match that shall be found.</param>
/// <param name="before">The number of lines before the occurence.</param>
/// <param name="after">The number of lines after the occurence.</param>
/// <returns>All lines containing the "match" including "before" lines before and "after" lines after.</returns>
private List<string> GetMatchingLines(List<string> lines, string match, int before = 0, int after = 0)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(lines[i], match, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            for (int j = i - before; j < i + after; j++)
            {
                if (j >= 0 && j < lines.Count)
                {
                    result.Add(lines[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Taking your code into account the method would be called in some way like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(textBox7.Text);
List<string> result = new List<string>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox9.Text))
{
    result.AddRange(GetMatchingLines(lines.ToList(), textBox9.Text, 2, 2));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox10.Text))
{
    result.AddRange(GetMatchingLines(lines.ToList(), textBox10.Text, 2, 2));
}

File.WriteAllLines(textBox8.Text, result);
```

Comment: Are the two methods you posted both the same thing just one is accounted for my code? Why do they look so different?

Comment: The last one shows how you can use the method I wrote in the context of your example code ;-) So you could write the last code in the button_click event.

Comment: Cool, so I can just put that last snippet in my button and it should work? When I put it in, I get an error for GetMatchingLines? I added the first method you posted before the button click and then added the second method into the button handler. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, should be correct. The method `GetMatchingLines` must be on the same hierarchical level like your button method. The code inside the button method should be the last one I posted. What's the error you get?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'ATT_Log_Analyzer.Form1.GetMatchingLines(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>, string, int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: Ok, sorry I made 2 mistakes. The first one was the loop which is not necessary and the second one (which resulted in your compile errors) was, that I specified `lines` instead of `lines.ToList()` where the first one was an array of string and the second one is a list of string. As the method is taking a list of string you need the second one. I corrected the example above.

Comment: Oh alright thanks! So because we specified the string to be a list not array we have to use the second one? And now to specify how many lines I want to copy before and after, I just change the int before and int after to whatever number of lines?

Comment: Yes, right. If it works for you please give me an upvote and mark the aswer as correct. Thanks ;-)

Comment: I already tried. But it says I need to have 15 reputation before I can give an upvote :/

Comment: But before you go, when I run it. It spits out so many copies of the same messages. A 4000 KB file turns into 48000 KB. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Btw, I'll definitely come back when I get 15 reputation points cause I have 13 right now, so just two more :)

Comment: It depends on the words you are searching for of course. And if you maybe entered just one word and left the other one empty, it will find "every line" I guess. Comment out the second `result.AddRange` and try it with entering just one word.

Comment: Oh ok cool. If I add && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox10.Text)) to the end of the result.AddRange will it ignore the boxes left empty?

Comment: No :-) You need to add it in a condition before - just a second, I'll change the code.

Comment: Man you are such a life saver. I am presenting this application to all my bosses and director tomorrow morning. I thought I wouldn't be able to finish this part of the application before the meeting, but thanks to you I could!

Comment: Glad that I could help you, I wish you much success ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate everything! Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for different lines with an integer difference between rows, you might want to edit your `foreach` to a `for` instead.

This would allow you to say things like

```
var thisLine = sArray[i];
var oneLineBefore = sArray[i-1];
var oneLineAfter = sArray[i+1];
sb.Append(oneLineBefore);
sb.Append(thisLine);
sb.Append(oneLineAfter);
```

Obviously, make sure you do checking to ensure that the lines before and after exist before accessing them.